# Comparing two lists in python in no specific order

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, how do I compare items that are not in a specified order between  `te` and `inc`

```
inc=[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['G', 'H']]
te=['A', 'B']
print te in inc # return True

inc=[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['G', 'H']]
te=['A', 'C', 'B']
print te in inc # return False
```

Comment: You're just trying to see if everything in `te` is also in `inc`?

Comment: By `#return False`, do you mean you want it to return False? Or do you mean you want it to return True, but it returns False, against your wishes?

Comment: For future reference, it's important to be a lot more specific about what you're after.  For example, the set-based answers will all fail if you want to get `False` if you're looking for `["A", "A"]` in `[["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]`.  You say you don't care about order, but you didn't say whether you cared about multiplicity or not.  It's important to think through corner cases and decide what behaviour you need before posting, as otherwise people have to guess to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're trying to do, but try:

```
inc = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['G', 'H']]
te = ['A', 'C', 'B']

def flatten(target):
    return_list = list()
    for element in target:
        if isinstance(element,list):
            return_list.extend(flatten(element))
        else:
            return_list.append(element)
    return return_list

set_inc = set(flatten(inc))
set_te = set(te)

print(set_te.issubset(set_inc)) # True
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why my answer got marked correct. I do everything that @roippi did, which you HAD marked correct then swapped it to mine. That doesn't seem to make sense...

Answer (score 2):

Rubbing my crystal ball a bit here, you want a flattened data structure (a `set` is ideal, since you don't care about order, just membership) and `all`:

```
s_inc = set(c for sublist in inc for c in sublist)

s_inc
Out[7]: set(['H', 'G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'])

te=['A', 'C', 'B']

all(c in s_inc for c in te)
Out[9]: True
```

Comment: You can use the `set.issubset` method here for (what I presume to be) a faster lookup. Also be aware that if his lists are nested deeper than one in `inc`, this will throw a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: No, that is not faster.  It also requires building an intermediate `set` out of `te`, which is a list.

Comment: For these exact lists, `s_te = set(te); s_te.issubset(s_inc)` is faster than `all(c in s_inc for c in te)`. I profiled using timeit. The difference can only get bigger if we artificially increase the size of `te` or `inc`

Comment: run it yourself :) http://codepad.org/bmJ74ZeR

Comment: if te=['A', 'C', 'B' ,'Z'] Z not in s_inc, return false. how to corrects !.

Comment: test if two element from te exist in the array inc !

Comment: @adsmith creating a `set` out of `te` is an O(n) best-case operation.  Simply doing `all` is O(n) worst-case but best case is O(1) (best case being when the first element is `not in s_inc`.

Comment: @softghost I don't understand what you're asking.  Edit in an example to your OP.

Comment: in the first example return true:

    inc=[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['G', 'H']]
    te=['G', 'A', 'H']
    
    s_inc = set(c for sublist in inc for c in sublist)
    print all(c in s_inc for c in te)

if Z added into te : te=['G', 'A', 'H', 'Z'] this reurn false.

how to pass Z

Comment: @softghost why on earth do you want that??  That test should fail since `'Z'` is nowhere to be found in `inc`.

Comment: `def test_union(te,inc): """USAGE: always returns True"""; return True` PERFECT!

Comment: @roippi in te i have other value out of the inc.

Comment: @softghost as you've been told about a hundred times in this question: WE DON'T UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU'RE TRYING TO DO. We're literally guessing.